# How to fill in a table using 2 data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame that looks like a table like follows:

```
1. DueDate    |    item1    |     item2    |    item3    |    item4

2. 1/1/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     nan     |     nan
3. 1/2/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     nan     |     nan
4. 1/3/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     nan     |     nan
5. 1/4/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     nan     |     nan
6. 1/5/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     nan     |     nan
```

I have another data frame that looks like the table that follows:

```
1. DueDate    |    items 

2. 1/1/2018   |     item1
3. 1/2/2018   |     item3
4. 1/2/2018   |     item4    
5. 1/4/2018   |     item4   
6. 1/5/2018   |     item1
7. 1/5/2018   |     item3
```

I want to fill the first table with the matching dates and items with YES like follows:

```
1. DueDate    |    item1    |     item2    |    item3    |    item4

2. 1/1/2018   |     YES     |      nan     |     nan     |     nan
3. 1/2/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     YES     |     YES
4. 1/3/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     nan     |     nan
5. 1/4/2018   |     nan     |      nan     |     nan     |     YES
6. 1/5/2018   |     YES     |      nan     |     YES     |     nan
```

How do I go about doing this, I have tried a lot of things but I was unlucky.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below `get_dummies` with assigning to `df1`:

```
df1[df2['items'].str.get_dummies().columns]=df2['items'].str.get_dummies().replace(1,'YES').replace(0,pd.np.nan)
```

And now:

```
print(df1)
```

Is:

```
    DueDate item1  item2 item3 item4
0  1/1/2018   YES    NaN   NaN   NaN
1  1/2/2018   NaN    NaN   YES   NaN
2  1/3/2018   NaN    NaN   NaN   YES
3  1/4/2018   NaN    NaN   NaN   YES
4  1/5/2018   YES    NaN   NaN   NaN
```